# do I need to install sqlite software to connect in java?

Tags: java, sqlite, database-connection

To make connection to sqlite database and do some transaction, is it mandatory that a database software should be installed in the machine. I have seen that some libraries just handle connection and transactions without even database software. Or did I miss to notice that there were some database is already installed? How does the connection mechanism works?
A link to good article with detailed explanation would help me!

Thank you.

Comment: This link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html should help you learn how to work with DB in Java. You can also use Hibernate for this, but if you are a begginer I recomend using the old way. You should have the jdbc jars for sqlite in your application so that you can establish a connection

Comment: If the server is remote you don't have to install the database on the client.  You have to install the database on the machine that will persist the data to disk.  It had to be done once.

Answer (score 0):

You need Jdbc driver only or you can use ORM like hibernate.
Youtube has many tutorials about java and databases:

[https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=java+database+tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=java%20database%20tutorial)

If you are a begginer, start with jdbc with sql queries, later you should start using ORM's.
Probably you need to install mysql server or use this website https://www.elephantsql.com/ to get database instant.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. **Use your DB locally**:
   For this you will need to install SQLLite on your machine, and in your project use JDBC jars for the connections from your java project to the DB. You may send queries to the DB as a string like "SELECT XXX FROM YYY WHERE a>b" or use *Object Relational Mapping (ORM)* tools like [Hibernate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/orm_overview.htm).
2. If you have a **remote DB** installed on a VM on some cloud for example, then you don't need to install any DB on your local computer. But you will still need to use JDBC for connection.